# Simulating OnClick event for DataGridViewCheckBox?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridviewcomboboxcell

VB or C#... A trivial task at the first sight. For **DataGridViewCheckBox**, create **OnClick()** method which is called *if and only if* value of checkbox was **changed** by **user** (using <kbd>Space</kbd> or left mouse click).

Perhaps there aleady is such an event – **CellContentClick** – but it seems to suffer from bug related to order of events and changing value by <kbd>Space</kbd> does not work due to call to `EndEdit()`.

[→ view C# equivalents](http://pastebin.com/DGjV3d1g)

```vb
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
        Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    If IsCurrentCellCheckBoxCell(sender) Then
        DirectCast(sender, DataGridView).EndEdit()
        PrintValueOfCurrentCheckBox()
    End If
End Sub
```

**Are we able to simulate event which works seamlessly, without bugs?**

**Consistency criteria:**

*(just a standard UX – they should be obvious)*

- Change event should be fired when clicked *inside* the checkbox or after pressing <kbd>Space</kbd>.
- Change event should **not** be fired when clicked inside chackbox cell, but *outside* the checkbox.
- Change event should be fired only when value *changes* (true ←→ false).
- Testing for checkbox value should give result corresponding to checkbox state.

**Helper code:**

```vb
'result validation
Sub PrintValueOfCurrentCheckBox()
    If DataGridView1.CurrentCell Is Nothing Then Return
    Console.WriteLine(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex).Value.ToString())
End Sub

'universal helper
Shared Function IsCurrentCellCheckBoxCell(dataGridViewSender As Object) As Boolean
    If TypeOf dataGridViewSender Is DataGridView Then
        With DirectCast(dataGridViewSender, DataGridView)
            If .CurrentCell IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim currentColumn As DataGridViewColumn = .Columns(.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex)
                Return TypeOf currentColumn Is DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
            End If
        End With
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

(C# or VB – whatever you prefer.)

Comment: This is ridiculous. For elaborated question with several hours of research behind it I get a downvote, but for [quick, fire-and-forget answer](http://superuser.com/a/969019/287473), I get "nice answer" badge and +100 rep to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Call to `EndEdit()` needs balacing – add `BeginEdit()`.

I found the culprit. Switching check box using <kbd>Space</kbd> key did not work because `EndEdit()` isn't enough. It needs to be balanced by `BeginEdit()`.

```vb
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
        Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
    If IsCurrentCellCheckBoxCell(sender) Then
        DirectCast(sender, DataGridView).EndEdit()
        PrintValueOfCurrentCheckBox()
        DirectCast(sender, DataGridView).BeginEdit(false) ' added method call
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, detection of change of the check box and and reading of its immediate state seem to be reliable.